# Web hosting in parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, web-hosting

According to instruction in parse.com:

> **Uploading Constraints**
>
> There are a few constraints for hosted files:
>
> - Files are limited to 500 megabytes.
> - You cannot upload more than 500 hosted files.
> - Filenames should begin with an alphanumeric character and consist only of alphanumeric characters, dashes, underscores,spaces, and '@' signs. The command line tool will automatically skip emacs and vim autosave files.
> - You are free to upload hosted content of any type you want. Parse will infer the content type from each file's extension.

It's not a problem for other things except the 500 hosted files limitation. There are about 700 files even for a small bootstrap theme.Do you think it's possible to host a serious website with less than 500 files?

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on you and the contents you want to display on your website.You can shorten the files and decrease the memory size but there is a  possiblity of loosing some of the designs and functions by using less files.